# Typescript onPress With Promise Returned Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, types, typescript-typings

I'm implementing typescript into my project for the first time and I have an error coming from `onPress` which calls `toggleModal`. **The error is coming from onPress**

According to the [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid), DatePickerAndroid.open() does the following:

> Returns a Promise which will be invoked an object containing action,
>   year, month (0-11), day if the user picked a date. If the user
>   dismissed the dialog, the Promise will still be resolved with action
>   being DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction and all the other keys being
>   undefined.

Can someone clarify if the error is coming from the following and how to fix it?

- The promise DatePickerAndroid.open() since it the response may or may not be returned
- Do I need to type onPress as a function with `onPress: Function`?

**Error**

```
src/DatePicker.tsx:109:25 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<TouchableOpacityProps>): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.
    Type '(props: Props) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'props' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'GestureResponderEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': title, onPress, onValueChange, mode
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TouchableOpacityProps, context?: any): TouchableOpacity', gave the following error.
    Type '(props: Props) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void'.

109       <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal} style={styles.fieldTextContainer}>
```

**Types**

```
// TypeScript: Types
interface Props {
  title: string,
  onPress: Function,
  onValueChange: Function,
  mode: 'calendar' | 'spinner' | 'default',
  minDate?: Date | number;
  maxDate?: Date | number;
}

interface AndroidProps {
  action: 'dateSetAction' | 'dismissedAction',
  newDate?: Date;
  year?: number;
  month?: number;
  day?: number;
}
```

**toggleModal**

```
// Toggle Modal
  const toggleModal = async (props: Props) => {
    try {
      // Check Platform (iOS)
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        // React Hook: Toggle Modal
        toggle((modalVisible) => !modalVisible);
      }

      // Check Platform (Android)
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const { action, year, month, day } : AndroidProps = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
          date: date,
          mode: props.mode,
        });

        // Action: Date Set
        if (
           action === DatePickerAndroid.dateSetAction
           && year !== undefined
           && month !== undefined
           && day !== undefined
        ) {
          // New Date
          let newDate:Date = new Date(year, month, day);

          // Select Date
          selectDate(newDate);
        }

        // Action: Dismissed
        if (action === DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
          // Do Nothing
        }
      };
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

**DatePicker.tsx**

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal} style={styles.fieldTextContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.fieldText} numberOfLines={1}>{date ? moment(date).format('MMM Do, YYYY') : 'Select'}</Text>

    <Icon name="ios-arrow-forward" size={22} style={styles.arrowForward}/>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems associated with your `TouchableOpacity's` onPress

**1. Incompatible paramter in toggleModal call:** `TouchableOpacity` gives off the `onPress` callback with `event` as its parameter and you are trying to call off the `toggleModal` without explicit binding i.e. the system will try to pass in the params given by `onPress's` callback to the `toggleModal` which are incompatible as `toggleModal` expects a paramter of type `Props` and is getting of type `event`,

This should be fixed with an explicitly binded call : `onPress={() => toggleModal(props)}`

**2. The return type of the function being called off from `onPress's` callback** which expects it to be `void` and yours is `Promise` as the function is async.
You can solve it by declaring your toggleModal to be a normal function with Promise based code for your awaiting calls.

Coming to the **year** problem, its due to the fact that the year value is not assured to be always number, it can be undefined as well in cases which is also documented [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5cd0c8a4d24142a248ae0c52c8dc8f0c5464e2b7/Libraries/Components/DatePickerAndroid/DatePickerAndroid.android.js#L61).

*Hope this helps. Thanks. Cheers!*

Comment: Thanks for the help Suraj!